# Create an appointment in outlook calendar with C#

Tags: c#, outlook-calendar

I want to create an appointment in outlook calendar.I already made some code in which allows you to set your own appointments but is not working as it should

```
var pcaOptions = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
      {
          ClientId = "xxxxxx",
          TenantId = "xxxxxx"
      };

 var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(pcaOptions).Build();
 var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" };     

   // Make the interactive token request
var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();

    // Configure the ExchangeService with the access token
var ewsClient = new ExchangeService();
    ewsClient.Url = new Uri("https://mail.domain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
    ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);

Appointment appointment = new Appointment(ewsClient);
// Set the properties on the appointment object to create the appointment.
appointment.Subject = "Tennis lesson";
appointment.Body = "Focus on backhand this week.";
appointment.Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
appointment.End = appointment.Start.AddHours(1);
appointment.Location = "Tennis club";
appointment.ReminderDueBy = DateTime.Now;

// Save the appointment to your calendar.
appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);

// Verify that the appointment was created by using the appointment's item ID.
Item item = Item.Bind(ewsClient, appointment.Id, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Subject));
```

> exception:The request failed. Unable to connect to the remote server

Is there any solution to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: Share what have you tried?

Comment: Please share the non-working code.

Comment: Are you trying to work with Office Interop or using an Office365 API?

Comment: What is not working? Please be more specific, are there exceptions or what is happening?

Comment: above code generate Exception

Comment: Probably need to see the class as a whole and i can i check you are using the reference Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data

Comment: @CallistusAsirvatham Yes I Used Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data

Comment: Have you tried the debugger and did you go step-by-step? Which line is creating the error?

Comment: @SQLPolice Yes at last appointment.Save Generate error

Comment: @SQLPolice Authentication is complete but did not create appointment in outlook calender

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Can You Help me out??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After so much  finding Finally i am get answer.

```
                string ewsUrl = "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx";
                string userName = "outlookUsername";
                string password =  "outlookpasword";

                ExchangeService servicex = new ExchangeService();
                servicex.Url = new Uri(ewsUrl);
                servicex.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                servicex.Credentials = new WebCredentials(userName, password);

                try
                {
                    Appointment appointment = new Appointment(servicex);
                    // Set the properties on the appointment object to create the appointment.
                    appointment.Subject = "Tennis lesson";
                    appointment.Body = "Focus on backhand this week.";
                    appointment.Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
                    appointment.End = appointment.Start.AddHours(1);
                    appointment.Location = "Tennis club";
                    appointment.ReminderDueBy = DateTime.Now;


                    // Save the appointment to your calendar.
                    appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);

                    // Verify that the appointment was created by using the appointment's item ID.
                    Item item = Item.Bind(servicex, appointment.Id, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Subject));

                    MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Event Created");

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
```

above code use sucessfully event create in Outlook.
Thank you.